# Can't save the data in the file i created in the begining of the program

Tags: c

The program doesn't save the data in the file. It should save the results, and then display them on new row when clicking 2. I have been trying for several days without any success.

When starting the program, you should first create and name a file. Then when pressing 3, you should put your three names, and it should display your first two initials and your full last name, then it should save it in the file created earlier, but at this point it doesn't.. And finally when you press 2 it should show all the names saved in the program, each on new row. Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char fileName[20];
    
int createFile(){   
    FILE * fptr = NULL;
    int mode = 2;
    printf("\n Enter name of file : ");
    scanf(" %s", fileName);
    fptr = fopen(fileName, "w");

    
if(fptr!=NULL)
fclose(fptr);

return 0;   
}

void displayFileContents(){
    FILE *fptr = fopen(fileName, "r");  
    char c;
    long int count = 0;
    printf("\list of names\n\n"); 
    while ((c = getc(fptr)) != EOF){
    putchar(c); count++;
    }
    
    if(count==0)
    printf("\n Warning: File is empty!!");
    else
    fclose(fptr);
        
}

void addInfo(){

int i,h;
char a[10],b[10],c[10];
printf("Enter your first name\n");
scanf("%s",&a[i]);
printf("enter your middle name\n");
scanf("%s",&b[i]);
printf("Enter your last name\n");
scanf("%s",&c[i]);
printf("Displaying your name\n");
printf("%c",a[0]);
printf("");
printf("%c",b[0]);
h=strlen(c); 
  

for(i=0;i<=h;i++)
{
printf("%c",c[i]);

}
 
  
}
                
void menu(){
    char choice = -1;
    
    while(choice!=8){
        printf("\n\n\n #### Main Menu  ####\n\n");
        printf("\n 1. create file"); 
        printf("\n 2. Show the names of the group"); 
        printf("\n 3. add name "); 
        printf("\n 4. End program");
        
        printf("\n\n Enter your choice : ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        
        switch(choice){
            case 1:  
                if(createFile() == 0) 
                printf("\n Success : File created successfully!");
                else
                printf("\n Error: Can't create file'");
            break; 
            case 2: 
                displayFileContents ( );
            break;
            case 3:
                addInfo();
             break;
             case 4:
                end();
         
            default: printf("\n Error: Invalid Choice! Enter again");
                     getchar();                 
        }
    }
        
}

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    menu();
}
```

Comment: Consider using [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) or [JSON](http://json.org/). Read [*Modern C*](http://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) then [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and more about [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing). Read the [documentation of *every* function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) that you are using. Read the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...)

Comment: **StackOverflow is not a do-my-homework website. Your program has bugs at every 2 or 3 lines.** If you use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then use [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)

Comment: There are several issues with the program, but the one most relevant to the question posed is that the program never writes anything to the file.  It should come as no surprise, then, that it does not read anything back from the file.

Answer (score 1):

first of all the your create function creates an empty file. It will overwrite any existing. Also at the end you close the file so you cant add anything to it unless you reopen it.

```
int createFile(){   
    FILE * fptr = NULL;
    int mode = 2;
    printf("\n Enter name of file : ");
    scanf(" %s", fileName);
   fptr = fopen(fileName, "w");

   if(fptr!=NULL)
       fclose(fptr);
   return 0;   
}
```

So, modify the following:

```
void addInfo() {

    int i,h;
    char a[10],b[10],c[10];
    printf("Enter your first name\n");
    scanf("%s",&a);
    printf("enter your middle name\n");
    scanf("%s",&b);
    printf("Enter your last name\n");
    scanf("%s",&c);
    printf("Displaying your name\n");
    printf("%c",a[0]);
    printf("");
    printf("%c",b[0]);
    h=strlen(c); 


    for(i=0;i<=h;i++)
    {
         printf("%c",c[i]);

    }
    appendFile(a);
    appendFile(b);
    appendFile(c);

}

int appendFile(char text[]){   
    FILE * fptr = NULL;
    int mode = 2;
    printf("\n Enter name of file : ");
    scanf(" %s", fileName);
   fptr = fopen(fileName, "a");
   fprintf(fptr, text);
   if(fptr!=NULL)
       fclose(fptr);
   return 0;   
}
```

Well there are plenty of errors in your code... 
You should start with a tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_file_io.htm

Answer (score 1):

> when pressing 3, you should put your three names,and it should display your first two initials and your full last name, then it should save it in the file created earlier, but at this point it doesn't.

No, it doesn't. There is no code in your `addInfo()` function that would have the effect of writing anything to the file.